# Unable to execute HTTP request: ec2.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn failed to respond

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = AWSEC2Client.getAWSEC2Client(set basicCredentials :: accesskey and secreate key);
                ec2Client.setRegion(set regions);
final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration()
            .withConnectionTimeout(150000).withMaxConnections(200)
            .withRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(null, null, 3, true));
```

While Calling  `ec2Client.describeNetworkAcls();` getting following exception :

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:
>   ec2.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn failed to respond     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
>   ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
>   ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
>   ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]   at
>   com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]   at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
>   ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>   ~[httpclient-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:860)
>   [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:631)
>   [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:400)
>   [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:362)
>   [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:311)
>   [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.54.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:11095)
>   [aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.54.jar:na]     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeNetworkAcls(AmazonEC2Client.java:5644)
>   [aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.54.jar:na]     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.describeNetworkAcls(AmazonEC2Client.java:5656)
>   [aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.54.jar:na]

Please guide I am new to AWS

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beijing Region](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/12/18/announcing-the-aws-china-beijing-region/) requires separate credentials - not connected to other regions.

> Customers who wish to use the new Beijing Region are required to sign
>   up for a separate set of account credentials unique to the China
>   (Beijing) Region. Customers with existing AWS credentials will not be
>   able to access resources in the new Region, and vice versa.

Comment: Additionally, if you are hosting any kind of content you will need an ICP license. Have fun :)